# ICMP reply packets are exist, but cmd say "No ping"

Tags: cmd, echo, ping, wireshark, icmp

I try to ping my device.
My device supports ARP answer and ICMP reply.
I send ICMP request from CMD. My device receive one and fast reply to back.
WireShark see my reply, but CMD doesn't see and print "No reply".
How can I resolve this problem?

Here it's CMD output [image]

Also [WireShark](https://yadi.sk/d/GGEipSzL3LPJk2) file is attached.

Comment: SO community doesn't tolerate non-English stuff, but screenshot above is just an illustration of "Request timed out." output in CMD. Anyway, question is quite interesting: wireshark traces looks totally OK.

Comment: @nnovich-OK - Saying that SO does not "tolerate" non-English may be a bit harsh. The SO community generally does not understand non-English and does not have good ways to handle it. Perhaps there will someday be a MT in place so that each user can see questions and answer in the language of their own choosing.

Comment: @lit Wasn't going to offend anyone. I understand the reasoning behind English-only policy, but there are cases, when non-English content is easy to understand (like above: run ping locally and match the output) and hard to re-create in English for OP. However, IMHO existence of such content tend to cause downvotes even when content is optional/illustrative. I might be wrong. Would love to be wrong actually.

Comment: You might get more response in the Network Engineering site. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/